# Send message to LCD via Command Line argument using Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, command-line-arguments

I have a piece of code (From the Adafruit website) to write chars to the LCD. Is there a possibility of doing it via command line arguments?

Thank you in advance.

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
from subprocess import *
from time import sleep, strftime
from datetime import datetime

lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD()

cmd = "ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1"

lcd.begin(16,1)

def run_cmd(cmd):
        p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
        output = p.communicate()[0]
        return output

while 1:
        lcd.clear()
        ipaddr = run_cmd(cmd)
        lcd.message(datetime.now().strftime('%b %d  %H:%M:%S\n'))
        lcd.message('IP %s' % ( ipaddr ) )
        sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code from that example is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD()
lcd.begin(16,1)
lcd.message(someKindofString)
```

...where someKindofString is your message. So it doesn't look like writing something arbitrary is hard.
If it's more the "how do I know what the command line arguments are?" aspect, then you want to look at [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) ([tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm))